# WCF 4.0 and .net remoting

Tags: .net, wcf, remoting, .net-remoting, wcf-4

There is a solid comparison between WCF and .NET remoting on [A Performance Comparison of Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) with Existing Distributed Communication Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx) (MSDN). Many questions asked in StackOverflow regarding performance issues between .net remoting and WCF are linked to this page. But this comparison is now almost five years old and dates back to .NET 3.0. So something might have changed in the last five years

Are there newer performance comparisons between WCF 4 and .NET remoting? Is there any information available, if WCF 4 is faster than WCF 3.